# REST requests no longer able to authenticate after enabling Windows Authentication

Tags: rest, kentico

In Kentico 10, I had rest requests working fine within Kentico (and from Postman). After enabling Windows Authentication I now receive a 401 unauthorized message when trying to make the exact same rest requests. The user account making the request is a non-active directory account, and is not marked as an external or domain user. In the IIS authentication area I have Anonymous and Windows Authentication enabled. Do I need to enable Basic authentication there, or is there anything else I need to do so that my user account for the rest service can authenticate once again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do only basic or hash parameter authentication,  take a look at [Authenticating REST requests](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/authenticating-rest-requests).  Are you saying that requests that were working perfectly in Postman before, stopped working  after you've enabled Windows Authentication in Kentico?  Does anonymous authentication is enabled at your IIS?

Comment: The kb article linked says, "The Kentico REST service does not require Basic Authentication to be enabled in IIS. Keep Basic Authentication disabled...".

Comment: Enable Anonymous authentication if it is disabled